# How is the PUT request in this example using subresource is processed by JAX-RS run time?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, put

I am reading through this example of Storage-service example in Jersey Sample provided in [oracle docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5o5/index.html)

I am just unable to understand how this PUT request is resolved by JAX-RS runtime?

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:9998/storage/containers/quotes
```

here is the code snippet that corresponds to this request (taken from above link).

```
@Path("/containers")
@Produces("application/xml")
public class ContainersResource {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context Request request;

    @Path("{container}")
    public ContainerResource getContainerResource(@PathParam("container") String container) {
        return new ContainerResource(uriInfo, request, container);
    }

    @GET
    public Containers getContainers() {
        System.out.println("GET CONTAINERS");

        return MemoryStore.MS.getContainers();
    }    
}
```

But as you can notice, there is no method with `@PUT annotation`. But the `getContainerResource` method is called for `/containers/{container}`. In this method, a new instance of `ContainerResource` is returned. I am not sure how the above `PUT` request is processed. Please explain.

Here is the `ContainerResource class`:

```
@Produces("application/xml")
public class ContainerResource {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context Request request;
    String container;

    ContainerResource(UriInfo uriInfo, Request request, String container) {
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
        this.request = request;
        this.container = container;
    }

    @GET
    public Container getContainer(@QueryParam("search") String search) {
        System.out.println("GET CONTAINER " + container + ", search = " + search);

        Container c = MemoryStore.MS.getContainer(container);
        if (c == null)
            throw new NotFoundException("Container not found");


        if (search != null) {
            c = c.clone();
            Iterator<Item> i = c.getItem().iterator();
            byte[] searchBytes = search.getBytes();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                if (!match(searchBytes, container, i.next().getName()))
                    i.remove();
            }
        }

        return c;
    }    

    @PUT
    public Response putContainer() {
        System.out.println("PUT CONTAINER " + container);

        URI uri =  uriInfo.getAbsolutePath();
        Container c = new Container(container, uri.toString());

        Response r;
        if (!MemoryStore.MS.hasContainer(c)) {
            r = Response.created(uri).build();
        } else {
            r = Response.noContent().build();
        }

        MemoryStore.MS.createContainer(c);
        return r;
    }

    @DELETE
    public void deleteContainer() {
        System.out.println("DELETE CONTAINER " + container);

        Container c = MemoryStore.MS.deleteContainer(container);
        if (c == null)
            throw new NotFoundException("Container not found");
    } 


    @Path("{item: .+}")
    public ItemResource getItemResource(@PathParam("item") String item) {
        return new ItemResource(uriInfo, request, container, item);
    }

    private boolean match(byte[] search, String container, String item) {
        byte[] b = MemoryStore.MS.getItemData(container, item);

        OUTER: for (int i = 0; i < b.length - search.length + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < search.length; j++) {
                if (b[i + j] != search[j])
                    continue OUTER;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good question.  I did some searching to see what the default behavior should be when methods are lacking the http-verb-annotation.  No luck.  It may be specified, but I could not find it.  In the case where @PUT is not specified, I would have expected Jersey to respond with a 405- Method Not supported. I am even more surprised that PUT would be mapped to GET as PUT is much more similar to a POST.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but are you 100% certain that the curl command actually issued a PUT request and not a GET?  A sniffer could verify this.  Your syntax is correct, but the server is acting as if a GET request was sent.

Comment: @EJK: I am 100% confident about it. In fact, you can just download the code and issue curl I posted above. It is also given in the tutorial link I gave above. what is more intriguing is how this PUT request creates a resource assuming the PUT request is resolved. Because in the code, I am just returning `new ContainerResource(uriInfo, request, container)`, I dont know how a resource is created.

Comment: If you follow the link more closely, you will notice `curl -X PUT -HContent-type:text/plain --data 
   "Something is rotten in the state of Denmark"  
   http://127.0.0.1:9998/storage/containers/quotes/1`, creates a new Item resource but again, how it is again resolved is a big question to me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a documented feature called sub-resource locators:  https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html

```
@Path("{container}")
public ContainerResource getContainerResource(@PathParam("container") String container) {
    return new ContainerResource(uriInfo, request, container);
}
```

The @Path annotation above identifies a ContainerResource as a sub-resource.  Note that the ContainerResource does have an annotated PUT method that is being invoked.  If you need further explanation, I can try to expand this answer.

**Update**

This is not easy to explain, but here is a stab at explaining it...

Let's start explaining this by looking at the various URL's your classes support.  The ONLY end-point implemented by ContainersResource class is the following:

```
GET /containers/
```

This end-point is part of a top-level resource.  Obviously it returns the collection/list of containers.

Now what if we want an end-point to get a specific container by id?  Normal REST end-points would expose the end-point with a GET operation on the collection followed by the id as a path parameter (PathParam), so a call may look like this for container with id 27:

```
GET /containers/27/
```

One solution to do this would be as follows:

```
@Path("/containers")
@Produces("application/xml")
public class ContainersResource {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context Request request;

    @GET
    public Containers getContainers() {
        System.out.println("GET CONTAINERS");

        return MemoryStore.MS.getContainers();
    }

    //
    // This is a solution WITHOUT sub-resource...
    // Note that the Path annotation is same as you have it, but
    // now the HTTP method annotation is provided.  Also, the
    // method returns Container instead of ContainerResource
    //
    @Path("{container}")
    @GET
    public Container getContainerResource(@PathParam("container") String container) {
        // Go to memory store and get specific container...
        Container x = findContainer(container);
        return x;
    }

    //
    // Again, without sub-resource, we can define PUT method
    // on specific container id and again define the path param
    //
    @Path("{container}")
    @PUT
    public Response putContainer(@PathParam("container") String container) {
        // Process payload to build container, put into memory store
        Response r = putContainer(container, ...);
        return r;
    }

}
```

Not using sub-resources causes us to have to put multiple GET, PUT, POST, DELETE methods into the same class as we promote methods from lower level resources up to the top-most resource class.  It also causes us to have to define the path param for the container id multiple times.  This is just 2 levels of resources (the container collection, and specific container) so it does not seem too bad, but what about as our paths grow deeper?  Containers have items, so a fully accessible API may implement an endpoint that allows you to retrieve just the items from a specific collection, or even a specific item from a collection.  These calls would respectively look like this:

```
GET /containers/27/items/ (to get the items collection)
GET /containers/27/items/9/ (to get specific item from collection)
```

So now, our parent resource would need to define 4 separate GET methods.

To avoid multiple GET/POST/PUT/DELETE methods in the same class we could still break these into 4 different classes each with unique Path annotations on the class, but then if some term in the path such as "containers" needed renamed, we would have to update the code in 4 places instead of one place.  Also, all the path parameters along the path would have to be defined on each method.

To illustrate this, consider the ContainersResource class you provided that uses sub-resource:

```
@Path("/containers")
@Produces("application/xml")
public class ContainersResource {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context Request request;

    @Path("{container}")
    public ContainerResource getContainerResource(@PathParam("container") String container) {
        return new ContainerResource(uriInfo, request, container);
    }

}
```

The getContainerResource method declares that there is a sub-resource identified by the path parameter "container".  This could be implemented directly in the ContainerResource class as follows if we were not using sub-resources:

```
@Path("containers/{container}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public class ContainerResource {

    @GET
    public Container getContainer(
    @PathParam("container") String container,
    @QueryParam("search") String search) {
        System.out.println("GET CONTAINER " + container + ", search = " + search);

        Container c = MemoryStore.MS.getContainer(container);
    // do work
        return c;
    }    
}
```

Notice that I had to add the Path annotation to the class to define the end-point location and the fact that there is a path parameter.  Additionally I had to add a PathParam argument to the GET method (and would have to add it to my other methods as well) to know what the container value is.

To further demonstrate this, consider if we implement the ContainerItemsResource without using sub-resources:

```
@Path("containers/{container}/items")
@Produces("application/xml")
public class ContainerItemsResource {

    @GET
    public ContainerItems getContainerItems(
    @PathParam("container") String container) {
        Container c = MemoryStore.MS.getContainer(container);
        return c.getItems();
    }    
}
```

And the ContainerItemResource

```
@Path("containers/{container}/items/{item}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public class ContainerItemResource {

    @GET
    public ContainerItem getContainerItem(
    @PathParam("container") String container,
        @PathParam("item" String item) {
        Container c = MemoryStore.MS.getContainer(container);
        return c.getItems();
    }    
}
```

Here we go again repeating the full Path and having to redefine the container path parameter on each and every method.

Sub-resources provide an elegant solution that (1) allows each level in the path to have it's own class with single GET/PUT/POST/DELETE methods, (2) does not require redefining levels in the path in multiple places, and (3) does not require redefining query parameters on every method.  Here are the four resource files using sub-resource approach (only providing GET method for illustration):

```
@Path("/containers")
@Produces("application/xml")
public class ContainersResource {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context Request request;

    // Define sub-resource for specific container
    @Path("{container}")
    public ContainerResource getContainerResource(@PathParam("container") String container) {
        return new ContainerResource(container);
    }

    // Provide @GET, @PUT, @POST, @DELETE to get collection of containers

    @GET
    public Containers getContainers() {
        return MemoryStore.MS.getContainers();
    }
}


@Produces("application/xml")
public class ContainerResource {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context Request request;
    String container;

    // Constructor allowing it to be used as sub-resource
    ContainerResource(String container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    // Define sub-resource for items collection
    @Path("items")
    public ContainerItemsResource getContainerItemsResource() {
        return new ContainerItemsResource(container);
    }

    // Provide @GET, @PUT, @POST, @DELETE to get specific container

    // Notice that path params are not redefined...
    @GET
    public Container getContainer() {
        Container c = MemoryStore.MS.getContainer(container);
        return c;
    }    

}


@Produces("application/xml")
public class ContainerItemsResource {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context Request request;
    String container;

    // Constructor allowing it to be used as sub-resource
    ContainerItemsResource(String container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    // Define sub-resource for specific item
    @Path("{item}")
    public ContainerItemsResource getContainerItemsResource(@PathParam("container") String container, @PathParam("item") String item) {
        return new ContainerItemResource(container, item);
    }

    // Provide @GET, @PUT, @POST, @DELETE to get specific container items collection

    // Notice that path params are not redefined...
    @GET
    public ContainerItems getContainerItems() {
        Container c = MemoryStore.MS.getContainer(container);
        return c.getItems();
    }    

}


@Produces("application/xml")
public class ContainerItemResource {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context Request request;
    String container;
    String item;

    // Constructor allowing it to be used as sub-resource
    ContainerItemResource(String container, String item) {
        this.container = container;
        this.item = item;
    }

    // Provide @GET, @PUT, @POST, @DELETE to get specific container item

    // Notice that path params are not redefined...
    @GET
    public ContainerItem getContainerItem() {
        Container c = MemoryStore.MS.getContainer(container);
        return c.getItem(item);
    }    

}
```

By providing this example of four level deep resource using sub-resource, hopefully it clarifies what your code is doing. The sub-resource approach eliminates duplicated path and path param definitions through-out your resources making the code more maintainable and (opinion) easier to read.

Comment: if you can, please expand the answer. I tried to read the documentation of how sub-resources work. but did not grasp it well. kindly provide an explanation how the PUT request is resolved for the URI above.. Thank you very much

Comment: This is the best explanation I have seen. wish I could give 50 votes!!

Comment: NOTE: If you want dependency injection to work for your sub-resources, instead of using new to create them use an injected ResourceContext like this: resourceContext.getResource(ContainerItemsResource.class) and set the appropriate values before returning.