# How to separate subresource representations with Jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, resources, jersey

I'm trying to design a simple REST API with a root resource (users) and two subresources (friend list and profile). So i've wrote this cose

```
@Path("users/{username}")
public class UtentiResource
{

private UtenteResource prova;

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response doPost (@PathParam("username") String username , AuthDTO auth)
{
    new UtenteService ().registrazione(username, auth.getPassword(), auth.getEmail());


    return Response.ok().build();

}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UtenteResource doGet (@PathParam("username") String username)
{

    prova = new UtenteResource (username);
    return prova;



}

@Path("amici")
public AmiciResource getAmici ()
{
    return prova.getAmiciRes();
}


@Path ("/profile")
public ProfiloResource getProfilo()
{
    return prova.getProfiloRes();
}


}
```

and here is UtenteResource, which represents a single user and is associated with subresources

```
public class UtenteResource
{


private String username;
private String profilo;
private String amici;

private ProfiloResource profiloRes;
private AmiciResource amiciRes;

public UtenteResource (String username)
{
    this.username = username;
    this.profilo = URIs.UTENTE_RES + "/" + username + URIs.PROFILO_SUBRES;
    this.amici = URIs.UTENTE_RES + "/" + username + URIs.AMICI_SUBRES;

}

public String getProfilo()
{
    return profilo;
}

public String getAmici()
{
    return amici;
}



public String getUsername()
{
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username)
{
    this.username = username;
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ProfiloResource getProfiloRes()
{
    return profiloRes;
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public AmiciResource getAmiciRes()
{
    return amiciRes;
}
```

I know, i shouldn't hardcode URLs but, one step at time!

by the way, this is what i get when i do GET /users/abcd

```
{

"username": "abcd",
"profilo": "http://localhost:8084/nice2mit_backend/restAPI/users/abcd/profile",
"amici": "http://localhost:8084/nice2mit_backend/restAPI/users/abcd/amici",
"profiloRes": null,
"amiciRes": null

}
```

but i don't want "profiloRes" and "amiciRes" in my response body, beacause i want to get them navigating with GET users/abcd/amici and GET users/abcd/profile

So, how to make it?

Comment: Here is a good description of using sub-resources, maybe it will help you figure out the problem you are having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270706/how-is-the-put-request-in-this-example-using-subresource-is-processed-by-jax-rs/26284280#26284280

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good description of using sub-resources, maybe it will help you figure out the problem you are having:

[How is the PUT request in this example using subresource is processed by JAX-RS run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270706/how-is-the-put-request-in-this-example-using-subresource-is-processed-by-jax-rs/26284280#26284280)

I've not validated the following code, so there may be typos, but structurally, this works.  First you define the UtenteCollectionResource that has a sub-resource of only UtenteResource

```
@Path("users")
public class UtenteCollectionResource
{

/*
 * Path annotation with param username defined here when using sub-resources,
 * not in the top-level resource
 */
@Path({username})
public UtenteResource doGet (@PathParam("username") String username)
{
    return new UtenteResource (username);
}

/*
 * Provide @GET, @PUT, @POST, @DELETE to get collection of containers
 *
 * Please note that the following is not best-practice -- you should POST to the
 * collection when creating a new element, not POST to specific element.  The
 * following may work for you, but please revisit after you get sub-resources
 * working.  The username should NOT be coming in on the path in this case.
 */
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path({username})
public Response doPost (@PathParam("username") String username , AuthDTO auth)
{
    new UtenteService ().registrazione(username, auth.getPassword(), auth.getEmail());
    return Response.ok().build();
}

}
```

And here would be the UtenteResource:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UtenteResource
{

private String username;
private String profiloPath;
private String amiciPath;

/*
 * Constructor allowing it to be used as sub-resource
 */
public UtenteResource (String username)
{
    this.username = username;
    this.profiloPath = URIs.UTENTE_RES + "/" + username + URIs.PROFILO_SUBRES;
    this.amiciPath = URIs.UTENTE_RES + "/" + username + URIs.AMICI_SUBRES;
}

/*
 * Provide @GET, @PUT, @POST, @DELETE to get specific utente
 * Notice that path params are not redefined...
 */
@GET
public Utente getUtente() {
    return new Utente(username, profilioPath, amiciPath);
}    

/*
 * Define sub-resource for profilio
 */
@Path("profilio")
public ProfiloResource getProfiloResource()
{
    return new ProfilioResource(username);
}

/*
 * Define sub-resource for amici
 */
@Path("amici")
public AmiciResource getAmiciResource()
{
    return new AmiciResource(username);
}

/*
 *  These getters/setters will have nothing to do with the REST exposure
 */
public String getProfiloPath() { return profiloPath; }
public String getAmiciPath() { return amiciPath; }
public String getUsername() { return username; }
public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }

}
```

I am unsure of what content is coming back in the amici and profilio payloads, so here is just an outline for those sub-resources:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AmiciResource {

private String username;

/*
 * Constructor allowing it to be used as sub-resource
 */
public AmiciResource (String username)
{
    this.username = username;
}

/*
 * Provide @GET, @PUT, @POST, @DELETE to get specific amici
 * Notice that path params are not redefined...
 */
@GET
public Amici getAmici() {
    // however you build the amici object here
    return new Amici(username);
}    

}

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ProfilioResource {

private String username;

/*
 * Constructor allowing it to be used as sub-resource
 */
public ProfilioResource (String username)
{
    this.username = username;
}

/*
 * Provide @GET, @PUT, @POST, @DELETE to get specific profilio
 * Notice that path params are not redefined...
 */
@GET
public Profilio getProfilio() {
    // however you build the profilio object here
    return new Profilio(username);
}    

}
```